# DOM element delegation and some information on target and currentTarget

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I had a look at some topics here regarding e/event.target vs event.currentTarget and this has helped me immensely when it comes to understanding the difference but obviously I have a long way to go still.

```
<body onload="attachEventsListeners()">
<main>
    <h1>Time Converter</h1>
    <div>
        <label for="days">Days: </label>
        <input type="text" id="days">
        <input id="daysBtn" type="button" value="Convert">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="hours">Hours: </label>
        <input type="text" id="hours">
        <input id="hoursBtn" type="button" value="Convert">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="minutes">Minutes: </label>
        <input type="text" id="minutes">
        <input id="minutesBtn" type="button" value="Convert">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="seconds">Seconds: </label>
        <input type="text" id="seconds">
        <input id="secondsBtn" type="button" value="Convert">
    </div>
</main>
```

This is the body of a HTML document I am looking at. There is a task I have to do with it but I don't want anyone to write my code or anything of that sort. I just need some help with delegation when it comes to DOM elements.

I am trying to get access to each and every button within the divs of the skeleton.
With my limited knowledge I have decided to do this:

```
let divElements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

This, as far as I know, will give me a NodeList which I can iterate.
Ok fine. I then decide to add event listeners to every div element and try to console out the type of the target which triggers the event. As far as I know currentTarget is always what is directly attached to the eventListener and target is what the event is dispatched to(so to say).

```
divElements.forEach(d=>d.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    console.log(e.target.type);
}))
```

When I click on Days in the first div I get both text and undefined - two rows of text. When I click on everything else in the first div I get just one. Why is that? Is my way of selecting(going from the divs a good idea or no?). Any help or links to something which you think is a relevant read would be appreciated!

Comment: You are facing a quite complicated edge case here. I'm afraid it will make things complicated to you. The crux of the issue is that `<label>` is a special element, that will delegate its click event to its linked `<input>`. So you actually get 2 events, the one you triggered, on the `<label>`, and the one on the `<input>` that the `<label>` triggered. Maybe it would be best to avoid the `<label>` in your tests if it's really your first steps into DOM events.

Comment: The main question is, why do you care for click events on those elements? These are kind of irrelevant. If you need this to keep track of focus, use `focusin` and `focusout`.